# Stop auto-dimming automatically

Tags: screen, power-management

I've noticed my Mac didn't retain the brightness I set with the keys.

How do you stop it from auto-dimming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have *"Automatically adjust brightness"* turned on in the Display preference panel?